# IE not respecting media queries - is there a work around?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm relatively new to this so please excuse my novice question.

I am making a responsive site based on the Zurb responsive framework, and using firebug in Firefox the site looks as it should in Chrome/Safari/Firefox however however IE ignores the media queries so various margins etc don't disappear as the screen size is reduced.

Is there a way to get IE to respect media queries so it behaves like other browsers?

Thank you in advance for any time you may take to reply.

Kind regards,

Sam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of JS libraries that can give IE the same media query functionality as other browsers:

**Respond**

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

**CSS3 madiaqueries**

http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/